# AVAudioEngine correct way to disconnect nodes

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I am confused by `disconnect` API of `AVAudioEngine`. I have the following code:

```
 engine.connect(engine.inputNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
```

I now need to disconnect these two nodes. What is the corresponding statement to disconnect them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

`engine.disconnectNodeInput(engine.mainMixerNode)`

or

`engine.disconnectNodeOutput(engine.inputNode)`

should break the connection been `inputNode` and `mainMixerNode`.

Comment: DTS says both the statements should be executed to disconnect the nodes, in your answer it says "or".  Specifically,

`engine.disconnectNodeInput(engine.mainMixerNode)
engine.disconnectNodeOutput(engine.mainMixerNode)`

Comment: I won't contradict a DTS recommendation but inspecting the graph's connections using `inputConnectionPoint(for:inputBus:)` and `outputConnectionPoints(for:outputBus:)` either call seems to break the connection between nodes.